# Java: converting char arrays to int

Tags: java, arrays, char, int, type-conversion

so i am trying to convert an array of 3 characters to an integer. Here is what i have so far:

```
   char[] characters = {0, 1, 2}; 
   int number = Integer.parseInt(new String(characters));
   System.out.println(number);
```

however this prints the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "�"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at usemyinteger.UseMyInteger.main(UseMyInteger.java:41)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  char[] characters = {0, 1, 2};
```

Because now `0 1 2`  are the integer literals , taking as the ASCII code for the character's .Not the actual characters  `'0'  '1'  '2'`

should be

```
  char[] characters = {'0', '1', '2'};
```

Comment: that would be the problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

For your good, please add 2 lines to print tmp string, it will help you to find real problem.

```
char[] characters = {0, 1, 2};
String tmp=new String(characters);
System.out.println("tmp = " + tmp);
int number = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
System.out.println(number);
```

And you will see tmp is unreadable string, now you should know you missed "'".